# Fourier Inverse Relation to Diffraction

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

My professor today in class stated that taking a measurement by light diffraction, such as X-Ray Diffraction, results in the same image as taking a 2-D fourier transform of an image in the lattice plane. Can someone give proof to this, or reasoning? I believe it, I just don't understand why.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_equation) and [possibly related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=diffraction+fourier+transform).